# How to draw complex function graphics

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand why Wolfram plots [$y=\sqrt{x^2-4}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsqrt%7Bx%5E2-4%7D) in this way:

[image]

I did understand why the blue line is drawn in this way (the real part). What I didn't understand is why the imaginary part is drawn like this.

Note also that a complex function is in the form $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ and shouldn't be drawn in a plane.

Comment: Looking at the first graph, it appears that they're imagining it as a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and treating the y-axis as the imaginary axis when referencing the orange line.  Notice that the blue line remains at $0$ between $(-2,2)$, indicating that the real part is $0$ for those values.  Honestly this is pretty cool and I have not seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are writing $y(x) = f(x) + ig(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions of a single real variable $x$. You see the plots of the functions $f$ and $g$.

Note that your function appears to be $y:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$, so you can indeed plot the real and imaginary parts as ordinary functions.